# how to sync web servers

Tags: linux, apache

I want to setup 2 LAMP servers for load balancing for webpages.  I will only upload files to server A and want the server sync the files from server A to server B automatically. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to keep two servers in sync. Store the files somewhere central with redundant storage, ie, use RAID

Comment: But I can't have a central storage, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use High Availability with shared storage software like openfiler or you can write a scripts for replication of data between both servers.